# React get the value within a callback

Tags: reactjs, callback

I have the following fuction in React:

```
  async agentGetDetails(){
  
  
  let contractInstance = await this.getAgentInstance();
  console.log(contractInstance);
  
  let details = await contractInstance.getAgentDetails({from:this.state.account},function(error,result){
    if (error){
      console.log("Error",error);
    }
    else {

      const {0:_agentAddress,1:_agentId,2:_agentCreationDate,3:_agentAvailableEnergyToSell}=result;

      console.log('the agent get details are: ',result,_agentAddress,_agentId.toNumber());
      return _agentId.toNumber();          
    }
  });

  console.log('function get agentdetails executed',details);

  
  
}
```

I am trying to assing the result of the callback to the variable details and print it on the log outside the callback, but I get an undefined value.

But when I print the result of the callback within the function I get what i was looking for.

See next the output of the 3 logs I am printing:

[log printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHrQJ.png)

Any ideas of how i can adapt the function to get the result assigned to variable details?

Many thanks,

Comment: Can you share the console log output?

Comment: Hi @dhruvtailor, i added the log I am printing.